# How to hide model details in url? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In get action method i'm returning view and passing model to it.

```
return View("MyView", model);
```

Then i get required view with model details in url.

```
host:/response?id=1&otherId=2 ...
```

I want to have next url:

```
host:/response
```

How to get it? Or how to map route the way i wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your solution explorer, go to `App_Start` folder. in that folder open `RouteConfig.cs` file. Open it.
You will show something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Shared", action = "WelcomeView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

change `url:` as you want to show. If you dont want to see `id` in your url, i recommend you to make a new MapRoute and dont include `id` in it